# Deleting Duplicates with a formula

Tags: excel

I have a sheet with Hundreds of thousands of entries. There is one column with names. The problem is I have the name on the list more than once. Sometimes twice sometimes several. How would I go about saving one of the names and deleting all other duplicates. I have a somewhat similar formula for numbers, but not sure how to do it with names.

**Example**

```
John
John
John
Greg
```

Comment: Why not use Remove Duplicates from the Data Tab?

Comment: Can you not use the 'remove duplicates' functionality that is found in the ribbon?

Comment: Yeah, Sorry Idk what I was thinking thank you!

Comment: or a PivotTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use **remove duplicates option** in Excel to remove duplicates.

If you want to use a formula, you can use for example the **Countif function** to count duplicates:

> =IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)>1,"Delete","")

[image]